# How do I get the appropriate file format from Open Map Tiles?

Tags: openmaptiles

I have downloaded multiple areas from OpenMapTiles for a project. Sometimes the file contains the extent or location with the date in the .mbtiles format. Other times I get a file name like 1_EOzgCOZOqPAcEFBcsVJbgd-bvHyz5Dw with no specified file format and it appears unreadable.

The only support for this site appears to be here. How can I get the appropriate .mbtiles format for all of my downloads?